# Pass 'file name' as argument to a class in "python 3"

Tags: python-3.x, class, parameter-passing

To read the header(common header for many files) of a log file(s). a class was created and calling the object of it from another file. The header class returns dictionary of the header values.

How to pass the entire file as argument to the header class from the child class?

Child class:

```
class fileLog(object):
   def __init__(self):
    try:
        # File path 
        filePath = "C:\FileLog1.log"
        file = open(filePath, "rb")

        with file:
            self.fetchHeader(file)

    finally:
        file.close()

# This method fetches the header information            
def getHeader(self, file):

    '''
        Get header information from header class

    '''
    header = HeaderInfo(file)

    header_dict = header.Fetch_Data()
    ....
    ....
```

Header info class:

```
class HeaderInfo(dict):
def __init__(self, fileName):
    header_dict = defaultdict(list)


    print(type(fileName))
    # self._object = self.file
    self._fileName = fileName
    file = open(self._fileName, "rb")

    self._dict = {}     
    ....
    ....

def Get_Data(self):
    return self._dict


hi = HeaderInfo('**** what to pass here ? ****')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hi.Fetch_Data('** what to pass here ? **')
```

I dont want to hardcode the filename in header info class, as multiple files can use the same class and dynamically the file has to be passed.

The error :

> TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fileName'

I know I am not passing the fileName, but **how to process the filename in HeaderInfo class**?

Answer (score 0):

```
hi = HeaderInfo('pass file name here')
```

Actually the errors shows that , init method has filename as arguments,if you call like hi=HeaderInfo(),it will throw a error like TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fileName',so pass the filename when creating object for the class

Comment: header = HeaderInfo(file) is called from the child class, and even in header class, this is the __init__ call : def __init__(self, fileName):
but, if the object is called this way?
hi = HeaderInfo(fileName)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hi.Get_Data(fileName)

NameError: name 'fileName' is not defined

Comment: You need to define Filename ,otherwise pass filename directly like 'test.log'

Comment: pass filename directly like 'test.log' in headerclass or from child class ? As, I want to get the filename from the child class and no hardcoding in headerclass...

Comment: @user301016 Do you want to dynamically pass the file name to be the header class?

Comment: yes please, as this header class shall be called from multiple python scripts, so each time the header class is called (header structure is same for all the input files), the respective input file shall be passed from the child class and based on the input file passed, the header class has methods to fetch the data. Sorry, if I have confused you

Comment: @user301016  As you defined the header class ,you must need to pass Filename as arguments  whenever you create a object.But I would suggests that, Better keep a filelogclass as super class and  inherit the method and attribute of the super class in header class